# Is PHPPageBuilder fit with Kunstmaan or Sulu frameworks?

Tags: php, symfony, sulu, kunstmaan

I was making some search about PHPPageBuilder, and I saw that it claims to be compatible with all PHP projects.

But does it fit with Kunstmaan or Sulu framework? Because I'm making all my project if it is, can you tell me how did you find the dependencies required to link PHPPB and one of these frameworks?

Because I can certainly use it, but how could I integrate it in my project, and how can I know all the dependencies I'll need?

I read all the documentation of Sulu and Kunstmaan, and PHPPB of course.

I saw that it's possible to integrate him in all PHP project, including those that use symfony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PHPPageBuilder, but from the docs it is its own Lightweight CMS, mixing it with another CMS like Sulu, does from my point of view not make sense, if you use Sulu you should probably should use the Sulu way of build templates and pages and not manage your pages via another CMS System / Page Builder would more confuse your content managers.

Sulu has its own Page Builder like functionality available via the Blocks, still Sulu follows seperating content from presentation. Sulu philosophie is that content should be structured the way that you can do redesigns without have to migrate data. That also why it is not inline editing, but with it's live preview you get nearly the same.

The Sulu Blocks feature give you possibility to ship different components for your content manager: https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.5/reference/content-types/block.html.